# How to not add trailing slash for certain directories on nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, configuration-files

I have this rule on a virtual host config file

```
  rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

it correctly adds a trailing slash if the request doesn't have a dot in it.
the problem is that this site has a REST API that will not work with trailing slashes under:

```
/API
```

for example in GET we have

```
/API/site/1/POSTS/23423
```

how could I make a rule for nginx to add a trailing slash for all Urls if not under /API ?

thanks

Comment: Use different `location`s. Put rewrite to location that need trailing slash

Comment: Will do, I hoped that it was possible to do the opposite, something like, if url doesn't begin with /API do this

Comment: @AlexeyTen you're right from nginx doc:there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead, match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then use location / to match anything else.